# How to hide the play/pause button and progress bar in youtube video embedded in html?

Tags: css, html

I have created on e HTML page with a you tube video link like -`<object width="456" height="230">
                          <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/kitfFWmLFJ8" />
                          <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                          <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/kitfFWmLFJ8"
                                 type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                                 wmode="transparent" width="456" height="230" />
                         </object>`
How to hide the play/pause button and progress bar in youtube video embedded in HTML?

Comment: As Tom said, the parameter `controls=0` seems to accomplish that – so just add it to the video URL, `http://www.youtube.com/v/kitfFWmLFJ8&controls=0`

Comment: check this as an example: http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/2hq22j/hide_youtube_progress_bar_to_avoid_time_spoilers/

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to using an iframe embed, you can add `controls=0` to your YouTube URL. For example:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="456" height="390" src="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/kitfFWmLFJ8 autoplay=1&controls=0&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"/>
```

Comment: but i want to use this code only, is there any solution for that?